# Firebird Trace SP's / Steps

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, trace, firebird2.5

I need a simple and free program to monitor all transactions on a Firebird Server.
I'm creating a web API that needs to mimic a user creating a new order in a custom made program.

Since I haven't got access to the source code I guess my best chance to properly insert all the data is to use the existing stored procedures. I can see all the SP's on the Firebird server and the details but I haven't got a clue which ones to use and in what order.

So the plan would be to monitor the activities while creating an order.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Firebird 2.5 and later come with the trace manager, but if you want a good user experience you might want to use a paid tool.

Comment: FB Profiler on SourceForge can be good enough. Intercept, save to DBF, open in Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice.org Calc - and try to connect the dots. You would have to connect connection IDs, transaciton IDs and statement IDs together, manually. Or, make some helper tool to read DBF and do it maybe

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark & Arioch for contributing.

After hours of failed experimenting with the included fbtrace.exe included in Firebird 2.5 installation i've decided to use "FB TraceManager" Trial version.

Found here: https://www.upscene.com/downloads/fbtm